# Spring: SimpleMappingExceptionResolver together with @ExceptionHandler?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I like [`SimpleMappingExceptionResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.html), because in one place i have all exception->view mappings for all controllers in web-app (i suppose that). To customize some exception in specific controller i would like to use `@ExceptionHandler`, but it doesn't work together - all exceptions are handled by `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver`. How to make this work together ?

```
@Controller
public class SomeController {
    ...

    @ExceptionHandler(SomeException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleException(Exception ex) {
         // ...
    }   

}
```

SimpleMappingExceptionResolver:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="defaultErrorView" value="error"/>
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        ...
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer: `p:order`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver" p:order="1" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver" p:order="2" p:defaultErrorView="uncaughtException"/>
```

Full story: [springsource forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?102713-Spring-Web-MVC-ExceptionHandler-ignore-when-exceptionResolver-in-place).

Comment: missing closing /> on second bean tag

Comment: if using the new infrastructure from Spring MVC (`RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`) you must use `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` instead of `AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver`.

Comment: we can use the HandlerExceptionResolverComposite as well now- http://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/spring-mvc-part-v-exception-handling/